# How to make Selenium wait until executed process returns

Tags: java, selenium

Using Selenium I execute an AutoIt script that opens Microsoft Word documents to compare them. Finally it saves the documents.

The Selenium script does not wait until the AutoIt executable is finished. How can I make Selenium script do this?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Hope This may help you.

```
Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Location to your script");
InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
 int retCode = 0;
    while(retCode != -1)
    {
    retCode = is.read();
    } 
System.Out.println("Now Exiting");
```